# Construction of Halbach Array

Tags: electromagnetism, halbach-array

Would it be feasible to construct a [Halbach cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array#Halbach_cylinder) from a cylindrical bird cage of diametrically polarized permanent magnetic discs or rods?

If so, would it be possible to stack and bond discs?

I am entertaining the idea of cutting or bonding a half round on one end of the rods or stacks to permit them to mate with shafts to swing the array ninety degrees to reverse the field.

Alternatively would it be possible to construct a flat array permanent magnets aligned vertically north-south separated by electromagnets aligned east-west.  Could the flux of the north-south field be controlled by varying the flux of the east-west electromagnets?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: From you description I can't tell what you are trying to do.  I can tell you that I've made Halbach arrays by using superglue to bond 12 circular segments into a ring.

Comment: I want to induce variable eddy currents in a rotating aluminum disk or cylinder connected to a piece of exercise equipment.